# The page is not going through after all, I feel I did everything right. Can someone spot my mistake

Tags: python, html, django

The page is not going through. I can't spot where I've gone wrong. It shows:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/deals/2015/03/first-lady/

Django 1.6
Python 2.7
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, Http404
from .models import Deal

def deal_detail(request, year, month, slug):
    try:
        post = Deal.objects.filter(publish_date__year=year).filter(publish_date__month=month).get(slug=slug)
    except Deal.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        post = Deal.objects.filter(publish_date__year=year).filter(publish_date__month=month).filter(slug=slug)[0]
    except:
        raise Http404

    context = {
        'year': year,
        'month': month,
        'slug': slug,
        'post': post,
    }

    return render(request, 'deals/deal_detail.html', context)
```

There is a link from the home page which directs to deals/deal_detail.html

```
<a href="/deals/{{ post.publish_date|date:'Y' }}/{{ post.publish_date|date:'m' }}/{{ post.slug }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a>
```

**deal_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{ year }}

{{ month }}

{{ slug }}

<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ post.description }}</p>

{%  endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^deals/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'deals.views.deal_detail', name='deal_detail'),
```

Comment: From the edit history it looks like _I_ added the group names to the urls.py but I didn't!

Comment: It is possible that you don't have a matching database row.

Comment: I am using myql as the database not sqlite3. I don't if its mysql that doesn't accept the query.

Comment: You can remove the second `except:` block to see what is the actual error.

Comment: DoesNotExist at /deals/2015/03/first-lady/                                                                              Deal matching query does not exist.

Comment: Then there are no records in the database that match the given conditions.

Comment: I think the problem is with the timezone. I have installed pytz. But that didn't help either. If I change the variable USE_TZ = True to False. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`?P` is only used when you want a substring matched by the group to accessible via a symbolic group name. See the [Python regular expression docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for a more thorough explanation.

Because you aren't referencing the regular expressions by name, you'll just want to exclude the `?P` altogether:

```
url(
    r'^deals/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(.*)/$', 
    'deals.views.deal_detail',
    name='deal_detail'
),
```

Comment: The original question didn't contain the group names, but has since been edited...

Comment: It's still not going through.

Answer (score 0):

Also try having just one `filter`, Django does sometimes produce odd SQL when chaining queries like that.

```
instance = Deal.objects.get(publish_date__year=year, publish_date__month=month, slug=slug)
queryset = Deal.objects.filter(publish_date__year=year, publish_date__month=month, slug=slug)
```

Comment: Changing the variable in settings from USE_TZ = True to False solves everything but will like to know how pytz is used to solve this problem